# How to disable node.js output wrap?

Tags: node.js, console, output

*code is unimportant here*
So on the right, in the output It comes out like this:

[image]

Because it is wrapping the output.

Instead, it should be something like this:

```css
`['.', '.', '.', 'W', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'W', 'O', 'W'],
['.', '.', 'W', '.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'W'],  
['.', '.', '.', 'W', '.', '.', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W'].`
```

So basically I want it to be just as this one:
[image]

Im working on a 3d array and I need visualization A lot. Thanks in advance.

Resizing didnt work, Couldnt find settings for it if there is.

Comment: that isn't vscode doing that - thats nodejs

Comment: don't use `console.log` with your objects - convert them to the way you want to in a string first or write directly to stdout.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, lemme change the question a bit